# SQLite strftime() weekday

Tags: sqlite, weekday

I have been trying with no success to to count how many values were created in a specific week day:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM packets WHERE strftime("%w", timeIn) = '1';
```

I have this values in timeIn

```
1472434822.60033
1472434829.12632
1472434962.34593
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

furthermore, if I use this:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM packets WHERE strftime("%w", timeIn) = '6';
```

I get

```
2
```

which makes no sense. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be storing the date as the number of seconds since 1970 (the Unix epoch) - a common representation. The time strings accepted by the [SQLite date functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (see the **Time Strings** section) default to interpreting numeric time strings as a Julian day numbers:

> Similarly, format 12 is shown with 10 significant digits, but the date/time functions will really accept as many or as few digits as are necessary to represent the Julian day number.

You can see this with the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 1472428800.6) AS t
```

the result of which is:

```
4026-48-26
```

For your date representation to be interpreted as a Unix epoch, you need to include `'unixepoch'` in the `strftime` call:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 1472428800.6, 'unixepoch') AS t
```

which returns:

```
2016-08-29
```

If you modify your `SELECT` to be:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM packets WHERE strftime("%w", timeIn, 'unixepoch') = '6'
```

you should see results more inline with your expectations.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but I am not getting any returns:
`SELECT count(*) as count FROM packets WHERE strftime("%w", timeIn, 'unixepoch') = 1;`

should it be better to change the format form the DB instead?

Comment: You could experiment with some `SELECT` statements to make sure the conversions are what you expect. For example, using the first value from your question: `SELECT strftime('%w', 1472434822.60033, 'unixepoch') AS w, date(1472434822.60033, 'unixepoch') AS d` returns `1` and `2016-08-29`.

Comment: thank you again for your kind response. I am getting `1` and `2016-08-29` respectively. Oddly though, `SELECT count(*) as count FROM packets WHERE strftime("%w", timeIn, 'unixepoch') = '0'` is returning `3`. Monday should be one ey?

Comment: If you are continuing to have problems, I would suggest using the `sqlite3` command line (or GUI tool like SqliteSpy) to run some `SELECT` commands on your data - to make sure it is what you think it is. Regarding using a different date format, there is not much point, but if you have a large amount of data, you might want to include a column that has a pre-caclulated day-of-the-week (calculate it with `strftime` on `INSERT`) so that the `strftime` does not have to be applied to every row when querying.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html): "%w" is the "day of week 0-6 with Sunday==0"

Comment: Thank you! Now is working like a charm! thank you for taking your time here. apreciated.